# How to write text in title slide of beamer class in top rectangular blue

Tags: beamer

I was not able to get the idea to write some text in top of the main title slide Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[10pt,numbered]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>

 \definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
 \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}

 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{pstricks,colortab,pifont}
 \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
 \usebeamerfont{child}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{mdwlist}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadows}


 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 \newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\bo}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath$ {#1} $}}

 \title{ Name of the Title}

 \author{ Presented by:{\textbf{Author Name}} \\Supervisor:{\textbf{supervisor name}} \\~\\ \vspace{2mm}
     Name of Department \\ABC Institute of Technology}
 \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in]{example-image-b}}
 \date{\tiny {\today}}
 %**********************
 \useoutertheme{sidebar}
 \makeatletter
   \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
   {
     \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
     \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
     \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
     \vfill
     \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
     \else%
       \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
       \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
       \vskip2pt%
     \fi%
 }%

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 \tikzset{
     tangent/.style={
         decoration={
             markings,% switch on markings
             mark=
                 at position #1
                 with
                 {
                \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
            }
    },
    postaction=decorate
     },
     use tangent/.style={
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
     },
     use tangent/.default=1
 }
 \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
 \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
    \makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \titlepage
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

 \begin{frame}{Outline}
 %\frametitle{Outline}
 %\scriptsize
 \footnotesize
 \tableofcontents
 %\begin{itemize}
 %\item
 %\end{itemize}
 \end{frame}


 \section{Chapter 1: Introduction}

 \begin{frame}{Introduction}

 \end{frame}


 \end{document}
```

Here is the sample

[image]

Comment: Can you minimise your example to only include the relevant code and not everything but your kitchen sink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like on any other frame, you can use the frametitle to add text on top of the frame:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\title{Name of the Title}

\author[Author Name]{%
    Presented by: {\textbf{Author Name}} \\
    Supervisor: {\textbf{supervisor name}} \\[4ex]
    Name of Department\\ 
    ABC Institute of Technology}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{whatever you want to write}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @BikiTeron You're welcome! And thanks for reducing the amount of code in your example.

Comment: Here i need some modification when i run the template there is a bottom text lines, so how do i diasble from appearing@samcarter

Comment: @BikiTeron Move `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` before the titlepage?

Comment: @samcarter, again good answer .. see if the following change of frontapge is appropriate: `\title{Name of the Title}
\author[Author Name]{%
        Presented by: {\textbf{Author Name}}    \\
        Supervisor: {\textbf{supervisor name}}  \\[2ex]
        Name of Department\\
        ABC Institute of Technology}`

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your suggestion! I edited my answer.