# Unable to change the line spacing in beamer heading

Tags: beamer

I am trying with `\setstretch{}` and `linespread{}` but no solution here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[10pt,numbered]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>

 \definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
 \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}

 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{pstricks,colortab,pifont}
 \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
 \usebeamerfont{child}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{mdwlist}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots,lipsum}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadows}


 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 \newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\bo}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath$ {#1} $}}

 \title{ Name of the Title}

 \author{ Presented by:{\textbf{Author Name}} \\Supervisor:{\textbf{supervisor name}} \\~\\ \vspace{2mm}
     Name of Department \\ABC Institute of Technology}
 \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in]{example-image-b}}
 \date{\tiny {\today}}
 %**********************
 \useoutertheme{sidebar}
 \makeatletter
   \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
   {
     \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
     \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
     \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
     \vfill
     \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
     \else%
       \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
       \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
       \vskip2pt%
     \fi%
 }%

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 \tikzset{
     tangent/.style={
         decoration={
             markings,% switch on markings
             mark=
                 at position #1
                 with
                 {
                \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
            }
    },
    postaction=decorate
     },
     use tangent/.style={
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
     },
     use tangent/.default=1
 }
 \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
 \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
    \makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \titlepage
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

 \begin{frame}{Outline}
 %\frametitle{Outline}
 %\scriptsize
 \footnotesize
 \tableofcontents
 %\begin{itemize}
 %\item
 %\end{itemize}
 \end{frame}


 \section[Chapter 1:]{ Introduction}

 \begin{frame}{\linespread{4}This is long chapter heading here and i am not able to chnage the line spacing here in this heading, i don't know what is the good solution for this}
 \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
             \begin{figure}

                 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
             \end{figure}
         \end{column}
         \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
             \begin{figure}

                 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
             \end{figure}
     \end{column}
\end{columns}

 \end{frame}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you still have far to long preamble, mostli irelevant to your problem  ... from  @samcarter answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414385/how-to-write-text-in-title-slide-of-beamer-class-in-top-rectangular-blue/414387?noredirect=1#comment1035110_414387) you should learn, how to write shorter ....

Comment: To second Zarkos request: please use the modified definition of `\author`, `\logo` and `\date` + `\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\tiny}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess with formatting commands in arguments of macros such as the `\frametitle{}` -- instead modify the appropriate font template:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size*={12pt}{12pt}}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is long chapter heading here and i am not able to chnage the line spacing here in this heading, i don't know what is the good solution for this}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer and wonderful coding@samcarter

Comment: @BikiTeron It would have been much quicker if there would not have been so much superfluous code :)

Answer (score 2):

@samcarter is simple to fast for me ... anyway, slightly different definition of font size line spacing:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\title{Name of the Title}

\author[Author Name]{%
    Presented by: {\textbf{Author Name}} \\
    Supervisor: {\textbf{supervisor name}} \\[4ex]
    Name of Department\\
    ABC Institute of Technology}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in]{example-image-b}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is long chapter heading here and i am not able to chnage the line spacing here in this heading, i don't know what is the good solution for this}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer!!!!